# I need to know how many times a string appears within another one! Using C

Tags: c, string, substring

Well, the title already says what I need. I tried to use a loop but it didn't go well, so, I came for your help guys!

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    char word[31], word2[31];
    int size1, size2;
    int i, j, k; // control
    int count = 0;

        printf ("\nInput the first word");
        scanf ("%s", word);
        printf ("\nInput the second word: ");
        scanf (" %s", word2);

// I tried  to make  a loop through the first string and if it matches a letter, it would loop through the others (if they are equal, we have a substring), but failed to put it on the `for` loop


printf ("'%s' appears %d times within '%s'", word2, count, word);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you looping through the characters of `word2` instead of `word`?

Comment: Am I? I thought this would go through `word`

edit: oh, actually I'm looping through the size of word2 because it has to end when word 2 ends, right?

Comment: Btw, I'm trying to do this without `<string.h>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`strstr`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strstr.3.html) is a useful function, it shortens your code considerably; when you find a match, just try again with the rest of the string;

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  const char* source = "aabaa";
  const char* string2find = "aa";

  int occurrences;
  const char *ptr, *lastfind = NULL;

  for(ptr=source; (lastfind=strstr(ptr, string2find)); ptr=lastfind+1)
    occurrences++;

  printf("%d\n", occurrences);

  return 0;
}
```

...or if you're really set on doing it without string.h functions, the code gets a bit more verbose;

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  const char* source = "aaabaa";
  const char* string2find = "aa";

  int count=0;
  const char *position;
  for(position=source; *position; position++) {
      int comparepos, equal=1;
      for(comparepos=0; string2find[comparepos]; comparepos++) {
         if(position[comparepos] != string2find[comparepos]) {
             equal = 0;
             break;
         }
      }
      count+=equal;
  }

  printf("%d\n", count);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was trying to do it without <string.h> :(

Comment: @user1949056 Ah, your original question did not state that.

Comment: I know, I forgot to put on the first time haha, but, thanks for helping anyway!

Comment: @TiagoC. Added a version without strstr. Sorry for the code style, it's been a few years since I coded C for a living and `vi` isn't my normal IDE anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strstr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/) to find occurence of string in other string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
    char* a = "aaaa";
    char* b = "aa";
    char* c;
    int count = 0;
    for(c = a; *c; c++){
        if(strstr(c, b)){
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("count %d\n", count);
}
```

Also, use [`strlen`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) to find length of a string..

Comment: I was trying to do it withou <string.h> :(

but, I tried with `strstr` and it goes wrong too :(

Comment: It finds 4 occurrences in `aabaa`...?

Comment: @JoachiIsaksson I've put my name: tiago and put 'a' for substring, it found 3 occurrences

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson it finds 3, but it's still a bug:)

Comment: I tried with 'arara' and 'ar', it should be only 2 occurences but it points to 3 on this code